# How to convert two functions from MQL4 to pine script

Tags: pine-script, mql4

i have a code in mql4 language and i want to convert the lines to pine script language.

```
  i=rates_total
  dist = 24
  hhb = iHighest(NULL,0,MODE_HIGH,dist,i-dist/2);
  llb = iLowest(NULL,0,MODE_LOW,dist,i-dist/2);
```

i need a similar code that works exactly like this  in pine script